# getting ajax to pass string variable from javascript to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the javascript I am using now

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var namer = sessionStorage.getItem("namer");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Antibiotics2.php",
            data: { 'name': namer }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the php:

```
<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
```

It throws an error and says that the index 'name' can't be found.

Comment: This is the updated question...still having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have replicated your set up and each time I am able to retrieve the variable set within $_POST. I have also avoided amending names as you stated that the session is being correctly captured in a similar question.

I was able to reproduce the error by setting the namer variable to undefined or by trying to retrieve a value which was not present.

Since I was able to send the variable namer as long as it is set then you will have to do a couple of things.

1. Check if the namer variable is set, perhaps client and server side. That is in javascript you would test if the variable is not undefined or in php you would check if $_POST['namer'] is set.
2. Your session may expire and therefore you are trying to retrieve a value that ofcourse is no longer there, this could be dependent upon which library you are using or settings you declared when creating the session

In both instances you will experience the same error and by doing some logic you will avoid this error.

Server side check - PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['namer'])){
    echo $_POST['namer'];
}else{
    echo "session capture unsuccessful";
}
```

Client side check - Javascript:

```
var namer = sessionStorage.getItem("namer");

if (typeof namer === "undefined")
    console.log("your session is not set");
} else{
    // you could place your ajax request here
    // or you could set the namer variable to a default value
}
```

Please if possible develop your web applications locally as it is easier to debug and as a final note it may be easier to use console.log(yourError) for debugging purposes rather than alert(yourError).

Comment: I followed your suggestion and the variable is set on both the client and server side. But it will not show up on the firefox page. I used firebug and looked into the script tab and the desired string variable is printing here. So is this a problem with my browser? I dont think it is because chrome has the same problem.

Comment: Ok great, so now that you have confirmed your variable is being set if you wish to display the value in a particular section of your site then you can use $("#nameOfDiv").append(msg); That is the value returned from your ajax request can now be added to any section of your site.

Comment: I want to use the string as part of a SQL statement. Is this possible?

Comment: It certainly is, I would recommend searching for php,mysql javascript/jquery tutorials that demonstrate how to use variables captured through an ajax request and then using php and mysql to get any information from the database. If this has helped answer your question then mark it as the answer please :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not telling PHP the name of the variable you're sending:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Antibiotics2.php',
            data: { 'namer': namer }
        });
});
```

And you'll want `$_POST` on the PHP side, with the variable name quoted:

```
<?php echo $_POST['namer']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a post call so you need to use $_POST instead of $_GET. Also, use quotes for string keys

```
echo $_POST['namer'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making a post request, you'll have to use `$_POST` to retrieve the data, also you have to send the data as key/value pairs, e.g

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        var namer = sessionStorage.getItem("namer");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Antibiotics2.php',
            data: {namer:namer}
        });
});
</script>
```

php

```
<?php echo $_POST['namer']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax code posted in the question works for me. But I am using Java and I thing

`<?php echo $_POST['namer']; ?>`

is the php equivalent for

```
<%= request.getParameter("namer") %>
```

in JSP

Please open firebug or chrome developers tool and look for the entire request parameters being sent by your Ajax request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I opened firebug and then the script tab. The request is successfully sending the string variable to php. But on the actual firefox page it shows that the variable is undefined. As per the suggestion below I tested the server and client sides to see if the variable was set to a value. It was in both cases but still not appearing on the browser. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: please check the "Net" tab in Firebug when the Ajax request is being sent. 
Open Firebug --> Select the Net tab --> Click the XHR option
then send your ajax request and check the POST parameters.